# Mathematical Induction - Is this correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

The question is :

Prove that

$$3 + 6 + 12 + 24 + ... + 3 \cdot 2^{n-1} = 3 \cdot 2^n - 3$$

for all integers $n ≥ 1$

My Solution (I'll skip the basis step and go straight to the inductive step):

II.
Assume that

$$3 + 6 + 12 + 24 + ... + 3 \cdot 2^{k-1} = 3\cdot 2^k - 3$$

Consider $n=k+1$:

$$3 + 6 + 12 + 24 + ... + 3 \cdot 2^{k-1} + 3 \cdot 2^{(k+1)-1}= 3\cdot 2^{k+1} - 3$$

$$3 + 6 + 12 + 24 + ... + 3 \cdot 2^{k-1} + 3 \cdot 2^k= 3\cdot 2^{k+1} - 3$$

$$3\cdot 2^k - 3 + 3\cdot 2^k = 3\cdot 2^{k+1} - 3$$

Cancelling out the $3$, I get:

$$3\cdot 2^k + 3\cdot 2^k = 3\cdot 2^{k+1}$$

Dividing both sides by $3$, I get:

$$2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1}$$

$$2^{k+k}  = 2^{k+1}$$

$$2^{2k} ≠ 2^{k+1}$$

III. Therefore, $P(n)$ is not true for all integers $n ≥ 1$

Is my solution correct? I find it weird that we were given a problem that isn't true but I guess that's intentional (unless I'm the one who's wrong.)

Comment: In general:
$$2^k+2^k\neq 2^{k+k}$$

Comment: *Hint:* $2^k+2^k=2\times 2^k=2^{k+1}$. This is the part where you made mistake. Otherwise it's fine, and you have *actually* proved it.

Comment: If it actually *wasn't* true, then instead of showing that the induction step fails, you should find a counterexample.  If the induction step *really does* always fail, then that should have implied that it was false for $n=2$, but as you should be able to confirm, $3+6=3\cdot 2^2 - 3$

Comment: Oh I got it! I forgot that that rule only applies to multiplication. Thanks!

Comment: You can also prove it using geometric progression: $3(1+2+\cdots+2^{n-1})=3\cdot \frac{2^n-1}{2-1}=3(2^n-1).$

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered by [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/177430/krish) (and others) via the comment. In particular quoting the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414359/mathematical-induction-is-this-correct/2901190#comment4985549_2414359):

> $2^k+2^k=2×2^k=2^{k+1}$. This is the part where you made mistake. Otherwise it's fine, and you have actually proved it.